# Error code with sorting program

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, sorting

I am currently trying to write a program that alphabetizes strings. I have one error. It's that minLocation does not take 2 arguments. I am fairly new to programming could anyone give me a hint as to why this part of my code is wrong?

```
int minLocation(string list[], int first, int last)
{
  int mIndex=first;
  int loc = 0;

    for (loc = first+1; loc <= last; loc++)
        if (list[loc] < list [mIndex])
            mIndex = loc;
    return mIndex;
```

---

```
void Sort(string slist[],int length)
{
   int mIndex;

       for (int loc = 0; loc < length-1; loc++)
       {
           mIndex = minLocation (loc,length-1);
           swap (loc, minIndex);
       }
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java - can you tag with the language, and tell us what `minLocation` is? A method you wrote yourself, or part of a library?
Either way, the error is saying you're calling `minLocation` improperly - check the function signature for how it should properly be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the definition of `minLocation`, we can't tell. But it's a safe bet that it doesn't take two arguments - compilers don't lie to you just for the fun of it, you can usually assume that what they're saying is true :-)

You need to find the definition, something like:

```
int minLocation (int loc) { ...
```

and figure out how you're *actually* meant to call it. Given that it looks like it's trying to find which of two indexes has the lower value, it may be that it needs *more* than two arguments.

And, on top of that, you need to decide whether you want that variable called `mIndex` or `minIndex`. Most compilers aren't quite smart enough to figure that out for you.

Based on your edits that `muinFunction` is defined as:

```
int minLocation (string list[], int first, int last) { ...
```

it seems evident that it also needs the string array as well as the two indexes. You will need to change the call to:

```
mIndex = minLocation (slist, loc, length-1);
```

And keep an eye on the `swap` call as well. It *may* have a similar requirement, based on the coding style.

Comment: I know, changed it because minindex and minlocation were blurring this late at night

Comment: @OurFamilyPage, you are calling the function `minLocation()` which expects *three* arguments with *two*, you've missed out passing in the array of strings. Have you fixed this?

Comment: @OurFamilyPage, that wasn't the immediate problem it's the _next_ one you would have found.